# Why my server cannot serve more than 400 concurrent connections

Tags: performance, webserver, apache-httpd, tcp-ip

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, kernel 3.13 in a Intel Xeon + 8Gb box. It has apache 2.4.7 configured in mpm worker with up to 4000 workers. The max bandwidth allowed by the ISP is 100Mbps.

If I test this server with apache ab locally:

```
 ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://www.mysite.com/test.png
```

And from another terminal I check apache workers:

```
 watch -n0 'ps -eLf | grep apache | wc -l'
```

I can watch worker count growing until reach 1000 threads serving the requests. So far so good.

However if I run the same test from an external machine, workers stop growing at around 400 workers. I guess this is related to some bottle neck in the tcp/ip configuration. Searching the web I have found several web pages explaing how to increase some sysctl settings to achieve more simultaneous connections. I have tried this:

```
 sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=50000
 sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=30000
 sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=5000
```

However repeating the test with these new settings makes no difference. You cannot see more than 400 workers simultaneously.

Where could be the bottle neck?

Comment: sysctl's parameter changed on both hosts ? no firewall setting (source host, target host, modem/router) ? no other limitation from ISP ?

Comment: Uhm... you are right. The client host was not updated. I have applied these same settings to the client and... same results: no more than 400 workers.

Comment: No firewall restrictions, just a default Ubuntu installation. Both peers are dedicated servers. The server at Leaseweb and the client at OVH. I don't think an ISP would restrict the maximum number of connections.

Comment: Wait... I have tried the test from two simultaneous clients and now at least 900 workers have been created. It seems this could be some per IP restriction somewhere.

Comment: if you are making many short-lived connections, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3923785/5008284) says to increase `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` and decrease `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout`.

Comment: The port range is important only at the client side. The default port range allows about 30000 connections. Once all client ports have been exhausted you should wait all TIMEWAIT connections to expire before repeating the test to the same IP + port. Decreasing net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout will reduce this 1 minute waiting period. However this does not change the results for the mentioned 10000 connections test unless I repeat it more than 3 times per minute.

Comment: I'm also encountering this with Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried all sorts of config combinations, but httpd just refuses to create more than 400 threads total (using MPM `event`). I get `apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread` errors, and there's this informative mailing list post: https://markmail.org/message/4sejmqsphho5tb3w. However, even after fiddling with systemd NPROC, NOFILE, and STACK limits, httpd still won't bulge. I might check again later with newer Ubuntu releases (i.e. newer Linux kernels).